# how to write action class to get json list from jqgrid

Tags: ajax, json, jqgrid, struts2

This is my action class:

```
private List<Employee> postData; // corresponding getter and setter

public String getJson()
      { 

    System.out.print("Sahi hai");
    System.out.print("postData  =="+postData);

    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;


      }
```

I have done struts mapping also.

Comment: my json data is [{"itemId":"mcw750","currentQty":"90","saleQty":"2","unitPrice":"100","salePrice":"200"}]

Comment: unclear what you asking, from jqgrid or to jqgrid?

Comment: I m sending data from jqgrid to server..

Comment: When I was learning I built of lot of examples on how to use struts2 jquery grid plugin, most of them can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041965/how-to-write-action-class-to-get-json-list-from-jqgrid I'm going to upload more related to your question. All are individual netbeans projects (few are maven).

Comment: sorry wrong link, correct link is : https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples

Comment: @user2592297 What exactly do you want to achieve? From your post, this is unclear.

Comment: i want to achieve json data (as mention above) in my action class.

Comment: I have used struts2-json-plugin-2.3.4.jar and its working fine.. I have checked in firebug that my ajax is sending proper data but in my action class i m getting postData null..please guide me..

Comment: this is my firebug response   {"currentQty":null,"itemId":null,"json":"success","postData":null,"salePrice":null,"saleQty":null,"unitPrice":null}

Comment: this is my struts.xml file    <action name="jsonaction" class="main.com.java.action.GetData" method="getJson">
        <result type="json"/>
    </action>

Comment: @user2592297 The data you send has not `postData`, you should build the correct JSON object.

Comment: I m sorry but i m new in json and struts2 .i m sending data like this var data = JSON.stringify(data);
                         
                            alert("The following data are sending to the server:\n"+data);
                            $.ajax({
                             type: "POST",
                                url: "http://localhost:7001/Final_Subgrid2/jsonaction.action",
                                dataType:"JSON",
                                data :{postData:data},
                                traditional: true,

Comment: i have jqgrid table and  i m selecting row then submit to send row data to server.in ajax its showing correct data for sending and json success also ..please guide me in proper direction

Comment: @user2592297 You should put json interceptor to the action config.

Comment: Edit your question to include the necessary information you had to add in comments. Include your package and action configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using stringify before sending, you have to declare "postData" as string in the action.

```
String postData; //with getters n setters

public String getJson()
  {    
System.out.print("postData  =="+getPostData());

return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;


  }
```

and in ajax give data as

```
 data :{"postData":data}
```

Comment: Not if they're using the json plugin.